# Automatically update package.json version and read it in code

Tags: javascript

I have logger which is displaying some stuff in production and i want to add version to this logger so i got better clue if/when deployment is finished. Is it possible to:

1. Update package.json version on merge
2. Read this version in code and add it to the logger

That will be really helpful

Comment: `node -e "console.log(require('./package.json'))"` prints the contents.

Answer (score 0):

for the second question if you have access to `process` you can read the `version` property of `package.json` like this:

```
process.env.npm_package_version
```

for the first question, that is a little tricky, you can use some packages such as [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) to run some `npm scripts` which you already add to `package.json`.

so you would listen to git hooks such as `commit` or `merge` and using `pre-` or `post-` scripts to run a command before or after a hook is fired.

so I guess if you can combine these, you would get your desired result